What is the convention for writing names of Quebec towns with "Saint" in French?
I think it should be Saint-Jovite, but I see St-Jovite, St Jovite, and Saint Jovite. Is it the same for street names, like la rue Saint-Urbain, le boulevard Saint-Laurent?
